# Error while trying to uncheck all the checkboxes in a C# app

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm new to C#.

I'm trying to `uncheck` all `checkboxes` in my application using this code

```
foreach (CheckBox control in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()) {
    control.Checked = false;
}
```

But in this line `CheckBox control in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()`, `Controls` is underlined in red. When I try to run the program, I get the following error:

```
Error   1   'FedApp.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Controls' and no extension method 'Controls' accepting a first argument of type 'FedApp.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**Note** I'm using the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
```

FedApp is the name of the application. Please how do I fix it. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What kind of application is this? Winforms? WPF? Console? WebForms? Windows Phone? Metro?

Comment: What's the type of `FedApp.MainWindow`?

Comment: @oded I'm not sure, How do I check?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm so new to C#, I don't even know the type of app. Please what do I do?

Comment: What kind of project did you create in Visual Studio?

Comment: using System.Windows.Controls, I suppose is a WPF app

Comment: @Chibuzo: I would strongly suggest you start learning C# from scratch, instead of diving into something big. Start simple.

Comment: Now, when you look at the `.cs` file for `MainWindow`, what comes after `class MainWindow`?

Comment: @Chibuzo - Then that's the type it inherits from. I can only iterate what Jon said - learn the basics before jumping in the deep end.

Comment: @Oded Thank you. I'll be grateful if you will tell me the topics I should cover as the basics.

Comment: Start with the language - keywords, concepts. You can start online with the [C# programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enum the controls in a WPF window I think you should do something like this

```
foreach (object o in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(FedApp.MainWindow))
{
  if (o is CheckBox)
  {
      ((CheckBox)o).Checked = false;
  }
}
```